# QuickBlox for iOS applications

Tags: ios, chat, quickblox

I am new to iOS development. I have to build a chat application and I found this website, QuickBlox.com, which provide code and back-end for helping build applications on various platforms. 
I had a doubt that I I take help from this website, will the applications build by me be my applications completely. As my concern is that if I build an application it should be completely my application and any other website or company's name should not be visible to the user's when it finally reaches them. If anyone knows about QuickBlox.com please clarify my doubt.

Answer (score 1):

The app is completely yours, you can publish under yor own name and use the business model you want.

You can check these case studies, donwload the apps and check it by yourself

http://quickblox.com/apps/

However, if you want to publish remember to have your own AppStore licences for Apple AppStore and Google Play.

Hope it helps,